# MySQL LEFT OUTER JOIN not filtering records

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying a simple LEFT JOIN query where I want the records from the LEFT table where there 
are no matches in the RIGHT table.

```
SELECT
LeftTable.ID,
RightTable.ID as NullID
FROM
LeftTable
LEFT OUTER JOIN RightTable ON RightTable.ID = LeftTable.ID
```

So, how do I select the rows where the result only contains records where NullID is NULL?
I thought an LEFT OUTER JOIN was what was required but all the Left records are being returned with matching and unmatching right records where I only want left records with unmatching right records.
The database engine is InnoDB.

For example, the query is returning the following:

```
LeftTable.ID, NullID
1, 1
2, Null
```

I only want result 2 i.e. where NullID = Null

I tried the following LEFT JOIN and is the kind of query I have been trying but I get the error 
"[Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'NullID' in 'where clause'".

```
SELECT
LeftTable.ID,
RightTable.ID as NullID
FROM
LeftTable
LEFT JOIN RightTable ON RightTable.ID = LeftTable.ID
where NullID = Null;
```

Hopefully this explains my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As documented under [Working with NULL Values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/working-with-null.html):

> To test for `NULL`, use the [`IS NULL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_is-null) and [`IS NOT NULL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_is-not-null) operators, as shown here:
>
> ```
> mysql> SELECT 1 IS NULL, 1 IS NOT NULL;
> +-----------+---------------+
> | 1 IS NULL | 1 IS NOT NULL |
> +-----------+---------------+
> |         0 |             1 |
> +-----------+---------------+
> ```
>
> You cannot use arithmetic comparison operators such as [`=`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal), [`<`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_less-than), or [`<>`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-equal) to test for `NULL`. To demonstrate this for yourself, try the following query:
>
> ```
> mysql> SELECT 1 = NULL, 1 <> NULL, 1 < NULL, 1 > NULL;
> +----------+-----------+----------+----------+
> | 1 = NULL | 1 <> NULL | 1 < NULL | 1 > NULL |
> +----------+-----------+----------+----------+
> |     NULL |      NULL |     NULL |     NULL |
> +----------+-----------+----------+----------+
> ```
>
> Because the result of any arithmetic comparison with `NULL` is also `NULL`, you cannot obtain any meaningful results from such comparisons.

Also, as documented under [Problems with Column Aliases](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/problems-with-alias.html):

> Standard SQL disallows references to column aliases in a `WHERE` clause. This restriction is imposed because when the `WHERE` clause is evaluated, the column value may not yet have been determined.

Therefore, in your case:

```
SELECT LeftTable.ID, RightTable.ID as NullID
FROM   LeftTable LEFT JOIN RightTable ON RightTable.ID = LeftTable.ID
WHERE  RightTable.ID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
SELECT
LeftTable.ID,
RightTable.ID as NullID
FROM
LeftTable
LEFT JOIN RightTable ON RightTable.ID = LeftTable.ID
where RightTable.NullID IS NULL;
```